no logro conectarme con el server usando retrofit2
anexo los archivos completos de mi intento de conectarme al servidor con retrofit haciendo un login en la app. el servidor me devuelve 3 variables y la idea es mostrarlas indicando que inicio sesión.
en el mainactivity se disponen los edittext y el botón para validar el inicio de sesión (usuario y clave) al darle al botón el muestra el usuario y la clave como prueba que recogió los valores que introdujo el usuario. la idea es que luego haga la consulta al servidor el cual devuelve 3 valores si el usuario y la clave coinciden con los guardados en la base de datos. si me conecto poniendo en el código un usuario y clave validos me retorna la información de ese usuario. pero evidentemente necesito que se verifique la información que introduce el usuario. pero no lo he logrado aun.
dejo el codigo para sus sugerencia y orientaciones.
MainActivity:
//MainActivity
package com.example.leccion1

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.leccion1.ui.theme.Leccion1Theme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import kotlin.math.log

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Leccion1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.login)
                    val usuariov =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.usuario)
                    val clavev =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.clave)
                    val botonBuscarv = findViewById<Button>(R.id.boton_buscar)
                    botonBuscarv.setOnClickListener {

                        val mensaje = "Usuarios: ${usuariov.text} y la clave:${clavev.text} "
                        Toast.makeText(this,mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this, pdc::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("usuario", usuariov.text.toString())
                        intent.putExtra("clave", clavev.text.toString())
                        val urlBase="https://myweb/mobile_app/"
                        val rtf = Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(urlBase)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build()
                        val servicio= rtf.create(getApiService::class.java)
                        lifecycleScope.launch {
                            val respuesta_servidor= servicio.getUserById(usuariov.text.toString(),clavev.text.toString())
                            if(respuesta_servidor.isSuccessful){
                            runOnUiThread {
                                if(respuesta_servidor.body()?.usuario == "err"){
                                    val m="Usuario o Clave Incorrectos"
                                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,m,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                }else{//se login y passw correctos
                                    val mensaje_inicio = "Inicio sesion como: ${respuesta_servidor.body()?.nombre} usuario : ${respuesta_servidor.body()?.usuario} y la cedula:${respuesta_servidor.body()?.cedula} "
                                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,mensaje_inicio,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }

                            }//respuesta del servidor satisfactoria
                            }else{//el server no respondiop
                                Log.e("error retrofit","${respuesta_servidor.code()} - ${respuesta_servidor.message()}")

                            }
                        }




                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    Leccion1Theme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }



ahora el modelado del response que se espera que son 3 variables
package com.example.leccion1
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
data class getModelResponse(
    @SerializedName("nombre")
    var nombre: String,
    @SerializedName("usuario")
    val usuario: String,
    @SerializedName("cedula")
    val cedula: String
)


y el getapiservice que hace la conexión es en este donde se scrachea la app
package com.example.leccion1

import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

interface getApiService {
    @GET("get_sesion_ini.php?login={usuario}&password={clave}")
    suspend fun getUserById(
        @Path("usuario") usuario:String,
        @Path("clave") clave:String
    ): Response<getModelResponse>
}

codigo del php que envia el json
$consulta =  mysqli_query($miconex,$sql) ;
    if($datos_users=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $data['usuario'] = $datos_users['login'];
        $data['nombre'] = $datos_users['nombre'];
        $data['cedula'] = $datos_users['cedula'];
    }else{
        $data['usuario'] = 'err';
        $data['nombre'] = 'err';
        $data['cedula'] = 'err';
    }
    
    //returns data as JSON format
    echo json_encode($data);


si pudieran orientarme seria excelente.
